# C# ListBox not showing added items when added from DispatcherTimer.Tick

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, timer, listbox

<s>This looks like a weird behaviour to me and since I do not like to blame anyone else than myself I spent hours by trying to fix this - but I do not understand this at all:</s>

I just noticed that the problem occures in a method called by a DispatcherTimer.Tick event. This could be a multi-thread issue.

1. I have a listbox:

   ```
   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ConfigurationErrors, Mode=OneWay}"/>
   ```
2. It binds to:

   ```
   private ObservableCollection<string> _configurationErrors = new ObservableCollection<string>();

   public ObservableCollection<string> ConfigurationErrors {
       get {
           return _configurationErrors;
       }
   }

   /// <summary>
   ///     Adds a configuration error to the window.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="ErrorMessage">The message to add.</param>
   public void AddConfigurationError(string ErrorMessage) {
       if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
           return;

       _configurationErrors.Add(ErrorMessage);
       NotifyPropertyChanged("ConfigurationErrors");
   }

   /// <summary>
   ///     Removes all configuration errors from the window.
   /// </summary>
   public void ClearConfigurationErrors() {
       _configurationErrors.Clear();
       NotifyPropertyChanged("ConfigurationErrors");
   }
   ```

`AddConfigurationError(string ErrorMessage)` sucessfully adds a message if it is called 
**from anywhere in my `MainWindow`**. 
(From the constructor and from anywhere else)

3. And I also have a constantly looping method (called by
   DispatcherTimer.Tick) in an instance stored in my `App.cs`, which
   contains the following code:

   ```
       //File exists
       if (configFilePath == null) {
           _mainWindow.AddConfigurationError("Could not retrieve the config filepath.");
           throw new InvalidDataException("Could not retrieve the config filepath.");
       } else if (!File.Exists(configFilePath)) {
           _mainWindow.AddConfigurationError("Could not find the config. (" + configFilePath + ")");
           throw new InvalidDataException("Could not find the config. (" + configFilePath + ")");
       }
   ```

The Exceptions are being thrown and the `AddConfigurationError()` is being called. I can also log the Message passed to `AddConfigurationError()` and it really works, however - my control does not recieve the binding update.

Is this because the DispatcherTimer.Tick runs in a different thread and bindings may not work as expected the way I wrote it? And how can I fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: From what you are showing here it's hard to tell why it wouldn't work. At least, you neither need the ItemsSource binding to be two-way, nor is it necessary to call NotifyPropertyChanged from your Add and Clear methods. The property does not change itself, but just the elements it contains, and that is already notified by the ObservableCollection class.

Comment: Are you probably calling AddConfigurationError on another MainWindow instance?

Comment: @Clemens What the hell? You are right. Calling Hide() or changing the state of _mainWindow in the Tick event has no effect on my window. How could that be another instance. I (should) only have one. I'll follow that lead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the methods on the proper MainWindow instance. You haven't shown how you create `_mainWindow`, but instead of calling

```
_mainWindow.AddConfigurationError(...);
```

you should call

```
((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).AddConfigurationError(...);
```

Comment: Now that is ridiculus. I did not remove the default startUp object in App.xaml, which was MainWindow. That became the window, being shown to the user. Then I created a second mainWindow in App(), where the AddConfigurationError() was called on. Obviously that did not have much of an effect. +1 for showing Application.Current.MainWindow - didn't know about that before!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. I use MVVM, but i think it should work from code behind

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
        timer.Tick +=timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddConfigurationError("err"); 
    }
```

XAML code

```
    <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding ConfigurationErrors}">

    </ListBox>
```

Comment: That is basically what I did. AddConfigurationError has just been called on the wrong instance.

Answer (score -1):

You cant access the UI layer from another thread you need to do something like this

```
yourList.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
{
    //add new items here
}));
```

Instead of "yourList" you can also use your mainform or something running on the mainthread

Comment: DispatcherTimer.Tick is already called in the UI thread. No need for Invoke here, and you are showing WinForms code, not WPF.

Comment: Yea, Invoke() is not a method in a window or listbox.